# System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe while running .Net Standard project in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, realm, .net-standard-2.0

i am creating an app in `xamarin` using .Net Standard so far i have installed following Nuget packages in my solution

PCL/.Net Standard packages

[image]

Android packages

[image]

Min SDK level is `Android 5.1` and max is `Android Oreo 8.1`.

When i run the app in visual studio VS2017 it runs for few seconds and closed down abruptly and throwing following error

```
04-06 02:45:11.182 6262-6262/com.org.sam A/monodroid-assembly: Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe' during startup registration.
04-06 02:45:11.182 6262-6262/com.org.sam A/monodroid-assembly: This might be due to an invalid debug installation.
04-06 02:45:11.182 6262-6262/com.org.sam A/monodroid-assembly: A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.
```

1. i tried cleaning the solution many times and removing bin and obj folders too but i am getting the same error.
2. I have not written any code anywhere as i am just migrating the project so this project is blank.

I personally think `Realm` has the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` reference and due to that its creating issue. here is the screenshot of realm installing from nuget

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this error, but it was when using Entity Framework from a .net standard library. This took quite a while to sort out! Hopefully this will work for you.

In the android project add the following as an XmlFile eg(UnsafeCompilerWorkaround.xml):

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="ReplaceRefAssemblies" AfterTargets="_ResolveAssemblies">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixedWindows Include="@(ResolvedAssemblies->Replace('\ref\','\lib\'))" />
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixedUnix Include="@(ResolvedAssemblies->Replace('/ref/','/lib/'))" />
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixed Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedWindows)" Condition="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedWindows) != @(ResolvedAssemblies)" />
      <ResolvedAssembliesFixed Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedUnix)" Condition="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixedUnix) != @(ResolvedAssemblies)" />
      <ResolvedAssemblies Remove="@(ResolvedAssemblies)" />
      <ResolvedAssemblies Include="@(ResolvedAssembliesFixed)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Edit the android.csproj file and add the following import

```
  <Import Project="UnsafeCompilerWorkaround.xml"></Import>
```

Then clean and rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in [Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1196). As far as I know, at this time the only known workaround is to use `packages.config` instead of `<PackageReference>` when referencing from `NuGet`.

It should be fixed soon by [#1356](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1356), hope this can help you. :)

Comment: for android it worked but for iOS it didnt worked , do you have any workaround for iOS

Comment: @Hunt, sorry, I know a little about iOS. But I think you could create a new question about this, there will be someone to help you to resolve this issue. :)